# Java Nimbus L&F - Button text color not working

Tags: java, button, look-and-feel, foreground, nimbus

i can't change the color of text button using L&F. I'm using this code

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.background", Color.ORANGE);
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Default+Pressed].textForeground", Color.BLUE);    
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.foreground", Color.BLUE);    
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Disabled].textForeground", Color.BLUE);    
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.disabled", Color.BLUE);    
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.disabledText", Color.BLUE);
```

The background is correctly Orange, but the text color is Black default

Here the full code, generated with Netbeans Editor (the above lines are near line 75)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Test
     */
    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("TEST BUTTON");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(74, 74, 74)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 240, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(86, 86, 86))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(106, 106, 106)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 81, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(113, 113, 113))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());

                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.background", Color.ORANGE);

                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Default+Pressed].textForeground", Color.BLUE);    
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.foreground", Color.BLUE);    
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Disabled].textForeground", Color.BLUE);    
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.disabled", Color.BLUE);    
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.disabledText", Color.BLUE);    

                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.textForeground", Color.BLUE);
```